# How can I distribute a SVC to different workers(on other computers) using dask

Tags: dask

I have a scheduler running on my PC and I want to train 10 instances of a SVC on different worker computers. I fiddled around but could not find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to train thoses 10 SVC with different hyperparameters and find the best one (aka hyperparameters optimization that you can do using gridsearchCV). I am also assuming that you are using scikit learn.

Usually you would train the SVC using a code like :

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.svm import SVC


# Loading the Digits dataset
digits = datasets.load_digits()

# To apply an classifier on this data, we need to flatten the image, to
# turn the data in a (samples, feature) matrix:
n_samples = len(digits.images)
X = digits.images.reshape((n_samples, -1))
y = digits.target

# Split the dataset in two equal parts
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

# Set the parameters by cross-validation
tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],
                     'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]},
                    {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}]

scores = ['precision', 'recall']

for score in scores:
    print("# Tuning hyper-parameters for %s" % score)
    print()

    clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(), tuned_parameters, cv=5,
                       scoring='%s_macro' % score)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print("Best parameters set found on development set:")
    print()
    print(clf.best_params_)
    print()
    print("Grid scores on development set:")
    print()


means = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = clf.cv_results_['std_test_score']
for mean, std, params in zip(means, stds, clf.cv_results_['params']):
    print("%0.3f (+/-%0.03f) for %r"
          % (mean, std * 2, params))
print()

print("Detailed classification report:")
print()
print("The model is trained on the full development set.")
print("The scores are computed on the full evaluation set.")
print()
y_true, y_pred = y_test, clf.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
print()
```

but it would only train sequentially on one thread.

If you install dask-ML, you can leverage a drop in replacement for grid search

```
conda install dask-searchcv -c conda-forge
```

Replacing

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

by

```
from dask_searchcv import GridSearchCV
```

should be sufficient.

However, in you case, you don't want to use the threaded scheduler but the distributed scheduler. Hence, you have to add the following code at the begining

```
# Distribute grid-search across a cluster
from dask.distributed import Client
scheduler_address = '127.0.0.1:8786'
client = Client(scheduler_address)
```

The final code should look like this (not tested)

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from dask_searchcv import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.svm import SVC


# Distribute grid-search across a cluster
from dask.distributed import Client
scheduler_address = '127.0.0.1:8786'
client = Client(scheduler_address)

# Loading the Digits dataset
digits = datasets.load_digits()

# To apply an classifier on this data, we need to flatten the image, to
# turn the data in a (samples, feature) matrix:
n_samples = len(digits.images)
X = digits.images.reshape((n_samples, -1))
y = digits.target

# Split the dataset in two equal parts
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

# Set the parameters by cross-validation
tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],
                     'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]},
                    {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}]

scores = ['precision', 'recall']

for score in scores:
    print("# Tuning hyper-parameters for %s" % score)
    print()

    clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(), tuned_parameters, cv=5,
                       scoring='%s_macro' % score)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print("Best parameters set found on development set:")
    print()
    print(clf.best_params_)
    print()
    print("Grid scores on development set:")
    print()


means = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = clf.cv_results_['std_test_score']
for mean, std, params in zip(means, stds, clf.cv_results_['params']):
    print("%0.3f (+/-%0.03f) for %r"
          % (mean, std * 2, params))
print()

print("Detailed classification report:")
print()
print("The model is trained on the full development set.")
print("The scores are computed on the full evaluation set.")
print()
y_true, y_pred = y_test, clf.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
print()
```